# Specific Shopping Cart Recommendations

Tags: java, php, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm trying to suggest a solution for a friend who owns an existing web shop.  The current solution isn't cutting it.

The new solution needs to have a few things that look like they're enterprise-only if I go with Magento, and $12k a year for a store with maybe $20k in stock just doesn't work.

The site should have items, which have one or more categories.  Each category may have a parent category.  Items have MSRP, and a discount rate by supplier, brand, and sometimes additional discount by product.

When a user buys something, it should automatically setup a shipping label with UPS or USPS, depending on user's choice, and build two invoices; one to go in the box, one to go into records.  This is crucial; it's low profit per item, so it needs to minimize labor here.

Need to be able to have sales (limited by time), discount codes/coupon codes.  Ideally would have private sales and/or members-only rates as well.

It needs a payment gateway; Paypal/GCheckout-only isn't going to fly.  Must be able to accept Visa/MC.

Suggestions?  I'm debating just building this myself in Java or PHP, but wanted to point my friend to a reasonable-cost solution that already exists if I can.  This all seems pretty straightforward to code, save working with the UPS/USPS/Visa/MC APIs, and doing CSS for it.

Comment: @Adam: Konakart wants $5k/year for Gift Certificates to be turned on, and I'm still digging to see how it works on the shipping end.  :-/

Comment: Yeah, that's expensive, and you need something sophisticated. More than http://www.opencart.com/ can handle?

Answer (score 1):

You can suggest Magento shopping cart for your friend, It would be better and flexible to integrate it to any of the web server either in Linux or Unix

And, regarding the payment process i suggest you to integrate Sagepay.
please try this link...

http://www.sagepay.com/products_services/sage_pay_go/integration